# PHP multiple row of forms, automating MySQL-input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I have created a PHP-site which basically is a site with some forms for MySQL-input.

This is how it looks right now. Pretty simple, fill it in and click submit to enter the data into the database.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/74uDQ.jpg

This is how I want it to look and work. I wan't it to be able to send multiple querys to the database with only one submit-button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXZkR.jpg

So the question is.. how do I solve this problem in the most simple and efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML should look like:

```
<input name="name[]" />
<input name="obp1[]" />
<input name="obp2[]" />
   <br />
<input name="name[]" />
<input name="obp1[]" />
<input name="obp2[]" />
```

and your PHP:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++) {
  // verify if all fields are completed
  if(empty($_POST['name'][$i]) || empty($_POST['obp1'][$i])) { // all fields here
    // add an error
  } else {
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$i]) . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['obp1'][$i]) . "')");
  }
}
```

Comment: But what if I only want to fill in half of the available forms half of the times then?

Answer (score 2):

In the name of each field, use e.g. name="opb1[]", this way it will turn into an array (opb = array).

Then you could do like:

```
foreach($opt1 as $k => $_opt1)
    if(isset($opb2[$k]) && isset($opb3[$k]) .....etc) {
        // use each row e.g. $opb2[$k]...
    }
}
```